# Advanced AND tax_query in sidebar with 2 taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, taxonomy, tax-query

I have two taxonomy : brand and product. In single sidebar I am displaying the brand and product of the post in the sidebar but I would like to display all the other product of the current taxonomy term brand. This is what I'am going to try but I have no error and it return nothing :

```
<?php
// get current taxonomy product term
$post_product = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'product', '', ', ');
echo 'Product : '.$post_marque;

// get current taxonomy brand term
$post_brand = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'brand', '', ', '); 
echo 'Brand : '.$post_brand;

// make the custom query
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
            $taxquery = new WP_Query( $taxquery_args ); while($taxquery->have_posts()) : $taxquery->the_post(); 

            if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;

            $taxquery_args = array(

                'post_type'      => 'any', 
                'posts_per_page' => 10,

                'tax_query' => array(

                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'brand',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $post_marque
                    )
                    ,
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $post_product
                    )
                )
            );

            the_permalink();
            var_dump($taxquery);

            endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

How to return all taxonomy product terms execpt current post term who have current taxonomy brand term of the post ? Is it possible to return term->name and term-slug ?

[Screenshot](http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/taxo.php)

This is a screenshot, for exemple current post will have taxonomy term brand = Antec and taxonomy product term = P280 and I would like to have all product terms with brand term 'Antec' by term->name except 'P280', so the result shoud return this terms : iSO, GX700, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `get_the_term_list` which generates an HTML string of taxonomy terms associated with a post and given taxonomy.

Try instead to feed the `terms` input parameters of the `WP_Query` with an array like:

```
'terms' => array( 11, 22, 33 ),
```

or

```
'terms' => array( 'term1', 'term2', 'term3' ),
```

In your code example you have

```
'terms' => $post_product
```

so you could use something like this

```
$post_product_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product' );
$post_product = array();
foreach( $post_product_terms as $term ){
    $post_product[] = $term->slug;    
}
```

to construct the `$post_product` array.

If you want to exclude some terms you can use

```
'operator' => 'NOT IN',
```

so your example could be:

```
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $post_product,
    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is that I don't know ID of the terms and they will always be different. I've tried your solution but it return only the ID of the current post term. I would like to have all the others terms by name.

Comment: I updated the answer. Since you are filtering the terms with the `slug`, I changed `$term->term_id` to  to `$term->slug`. So want to exclude the current post product terms? Then you can use the `operator` parameter, see the updated answer.

Comment: I have the same result, but it return the post term by slug. The post has only one product term, so if I make [code]$post_product_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product' );
it constructs an array with only one term but not with all others posts terms ?

Comment: this sounds normal, if the post has one product term, the array should only contain one slug element. Did you then add the above 'operator' part into the WP_Query to do the exclusion?

Comment: yes I did it but it always give me current post term

Comment: can you perhaps update the answer with your current code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, query wasn't return result because  args was after the query... Operator NOT IN is working nice and I extract product taxonomy terms of the query with  wp_get_object_terms(). All is working fine ;) Thanks

Comment: great to hear your problem is solved ;-)  There are many wrappers for `wp_get_object_terms()` and `get_the_terms()` is one of them. I would consider using `get_the_terms()` for the current post since it is using the object cache (see [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1052)).  Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you solve the problem, thanks.